# HTML Form Value = Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display "something" on the HTML forms textbox
this value should be a javascript variable

```js
var paramvalue = "something"
document.getElementById("client_id").value = paramvalue
```

```html
<form action="login.php" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="clientID" id="client_id" value="" />
       <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `var textbox = document.getElementById('client_id');`, then `textbox.value = `paramvalue`;`  will set the value, just as you've done.  input type is set to hidden so you won't actually see the form field incase you didnt know. If you want it visible `type='text'`

Comment: You have type= hidden in your input textbox. To display the textbox you need to remove it. Also, make sure the script comes after the HTML as you are not setting the value onload.

Comment: Your code seems to work quite right, have a look on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Loxos/juuq27ou/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('client_id');,
```

then

```
textbox.value = paramvalue;
```

will work.

Your issue is you have `type='hidden'` where it should be `type='text'` because hidden will not be visible. You also need to change it to run onload so you replace the value on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
   function init(){
      var paramvalue = "something"
      document.getElementById("client_id").value = paramvalue
   }
   body.addEventListener("load", init);
</script>



  <form action="login.php" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="clientID" id="client_id" value="" />
           <button>Login</button>
  </form>
```

Alternatively, you can keep your code, change `input type = "text"` and just move your script below your HTML code/ Form, negating the need for the JS function and the event listener

The user could also do :

```
<input type="text" name="clientID" id="client_id" value="" onload="init()" />
```

Comment: Please explain why separating `var textbox` and `textbox.value` makes any difference and why this couldn’t work with `type="hidden"`. Also, `init()` is not how you pass a function reference as an event listener.

Comment: Just to show the process. It can be changed if one would like, either way works though so this isn't a valid concern. Second, it is exactly how you add an event listener on page load for a function

Comment: No, no, no. First, you introduce two unnecessary steps which do nothing to address the actual issue, because they don’t change anything about the functionality of the code. Secondly, `init()` _immediately calls_ the function and passes `undefined` as an event listener. This is _not_ how you assign event listeners. At least you corrected that.

Comment: Which split the process up so the user can see and future readers who don't know you can chain things.   And I removed the accidental (), so unless you're going to provide an answer please stop criticizing unnecessary points (aside from the () error ).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the script after the HTML, since when it is run, the input field doesn't exist yet, so it will return an error.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="clientID" id="client_id" value="" />
    <button>Login</button> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var paramvalue = "something";
    document.getElementById("client_id").value = paramvalue; 
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, lol.. didn't see it ;) I'm on a mobile screen, so I have to scroll sideways to see that >_<

Comment: Done.. I corrected it. The solution is to put the script after the HTML

Comment: You might also want to look into using separate JS files and linking to them. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp